# My view stops working when call db connection

Tags: java, jpa, javafx

I'm trying to create a simple view which save data on mysql db, but when I call the controller function to save from the JavaFx Button it doesn't work, the application starts using the hole memory until crash. When I call from a simple static void main in terminal it works correctly.

I already tried to launch the connection as a thread but it also don't work, the application don't crash but the thread with the connection stays alieve until I close manually.
When I debug the application the Connection thread immediately turns into mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup
[connection thread] https://drive.google.com/file/d/19DfJ-eZPtk895rd0iZs_6HkOZIAPFD9v/view?usp=sharing

Main Class

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            URL url = new File("src/application/Cadastro.fxml").toURI().toURL();
            Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 358, 227);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Login Teste");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
   }
```

View

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="400.0" maxWidth="400.0" minHeight="400.0" minWidth="400.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.CadastroController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btnSalvar" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="226.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="174.0" text="Salvar" />
      <TextField fx:id="fieldNome" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="133.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="174.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="fieldSenha" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="188.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="174.0" />
      <Label layoutX="108.0" layoutY="165.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Senha" />
      <Label layoutX="108.0" layoutY="107.0" text="Usuário" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

View Controller

```
public class CadastroController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldNome;
    @FXML
    private TextField fieldSenha;

    @FXML
    private void onClick() {
        UsuarioController uControl = new UsuarioController();
        Usuario u = new Usuario(fieldNome.getText(), fieldSenha.getText());
        uControl.salvar(u);
        Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Usuario salvo no bd");
        a.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

   }
```

ConnectionFactory

```
public class ConnectionFactory {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private static synchronized void buildEmf() {
        try {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sistema");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManager() {
        if (emf == null)
            buildEmf();
        return emf;
    }

    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (emf.isOpen()) {
            emf.close();
        }
    }

   }
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
public class Usuario implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String nome;
    private String senha;

    public Usuario() {

    }

    public Usuario(String nome, String senha) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }
    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }


   }
```

Controller

```
public class UsuarioController {

    public void salvar(Usuario usuario) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sistema");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(usuario);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("USUARIO SALVO NO BD");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
    }

   }
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
 version="2.1">
 <persistence-unit name="sistema" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
 <properties>
 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/usertest?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
 <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>

 </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This problem is taking me crazy because the connection is ok, the view is running ok until I call a Connection from a javafx button if I call the connection from a simple static void main the data is sent normally to the db.

Comment: You posted a `ConnectionFactory`, I don't see you using it, though. First thing I'd try is to avoid creating an `EntityManagerFactory` for each call to `salvar`. This should ideally happen once in your entire app

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/sedj601/SQLitePersonTableViewExampleUsingTask) helps.

Comment: I found the solution, I need to start the entity manager factory before starting the view main method.